# Symfony:4 Expected argument of type "integer", "NULL" given at property path

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Getting below error,

**Expected argument of type "integer", "NULL" given at property path "experience".**

Code is as below,

```
->add('experience', TextType::class, [
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
            "message" => $this->translator->trans('Please enter experience.')
        ]),
        new Length([
            'max' => 2
        ]),
    ],
    'required' => false
])
```

When I submit blank form (create time), It show me "Please enter experience."

Now on edit form, If I insert wrong value (more data like 3434) It show me value should not more than 2 character

Problem arise when I send blank data on edit time.
Submitting with blank experience (its compulsory field in form), It gives below error

**Expected argument of type "integer", "NULL" given at property path "experience".**

I had tried different options from internet like setting "empty_data" to null or '' but its not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your setter method should allow `null` values if you accept ones, judging by the form:

```
public function setExperience(?int $experience): void
{
    $this->experience = (int) $experience;
}
```

Comment: To be super precise and if you want to have NULL value, you should avoid adding mapping to integer. Get rid of (int) in the body of above function.

Comment: If you want to be precise `?int` accepts both int and null. I don’t want anybody to put there anything else.

Comment: Sure, that's why I was talking about the definiton (body), not declaration - which is: $this->experience = (int) $experience; because if you leave it as you've written, having NULL in value will shoot to database with 0 as a default (int) value.

Comment: Issue also resolve by just putting question mark before type cast in an argument,
public function setExperience(?int $experience): void